# Понятие какое или понятие чего?

Tags: падежи, управление

Я о "понятии" в следующем смысле [отсюда](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_philosophy/952/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%95):

> Понятие — общее имя с относительно ясным содержанием и сравнительно четко очерченным объёмом.

То есть в смысле, близком к слову "термин".

Можно сказать *понятие "красота"* или *понятие "время".* А может ли быть также *понятие красоты* или *понятие времени?* Но только в том же смысле, а не в смысле *понимание, представление о?*

Если может, то чем определяется выбор? И правильно, что у меня в именительном стоят кавычки, а в родительном без них?

Answer (score 1):

> И правильно, что у меня в именительном стоят кавычки, а в родительном без них?

Всё правильно. По аналогии с *слово "красота"*.

> Если может, то чем определяется выбор?

Функцией, которую играет слово в смысле предложения.
Сравнить:
*Понятие красоты у этих художников разное.* || Восприятие красоты людьми. Именительный падеж не подходит.
*Понятие "красота" довольно относительное.* || Рассматривается само понятие.

Суть не в восприятии. При чистом использовании в качестве термина может использоваться родительный:
*Понятие красоты каждый трактует по-разному.* || В таком случае выражается **отношение** к термину.

Если же даётся определение понятию или описываются его особенности, то используется именительный падеж. Тогда слово "понятие" можно опустить, подправив согласование, — оно не является главным.

Comment: Я сказал "если можно".

Comment: И что?.........

Comment: Вы ж говорите, что нельзя.

Comment: Что нельзя? Не понимаю.

Comment: Если может быть понятие чего-то (р. п.) в том же смысле, а не в смысле "восприятие". Вы сказали, что в том же смысле не может быть, только в другом. А я спросил, чем определяется выбор только в том случае, если родительный падеж подходит к "понятию" как "термину".

Comment: На самом деле в этих примерах одно значение. Например: *Восприятие красоты довольно относительно.*

Comment: Я ж не про восприятие толкую, а про термин. Так, чтобы *понятие "красота"* и *понятие красоты* означало одно и то же.

Comment: В таких случаях использование родительного звучит очень просторечно. Если даётся определение понятию или описываются его особенности, то используется именительный, так как слово "понятие" можно опустить - оно не является главным.

Comment: Тогда я бы на вашем месте переписал ответ.

Comment: Ответ дополнен.

Comment: Да не может же, по-вашему!

Comment: Что не может? *Понятие красоты каждый трактует по-разному. Термин "красота" каждый трактует по-разному.*

Comment: То есть всё-таки можно сказать и *понятие красоты,* и *понятие "красота",* имея в виду термин, да?

Comment: Да. *Понятие красоты*, если выражается отношение к термину: *О понятии красоты можно спорить долго.*

Answer (score 0):

Все эти вопросы - "чего?" или "какой?" - не имеют, вообще говоря, большого значения и ничего не объясняют на самом-то деле.

Вот мои соображения:

***1) Понятие время***

Я думаю, что это сочетание определяемого слова *(понятие)* и приложения к нему *(время)*. Два разных имени одного и того же (слова "время", которое ты произнёс).

Первое имя (понятие) - оно общее, второе (время) - конкретное, частное. Так можно думать: время - это и понятие (слово с неким ясным содержанием), и одновременно время - это, кхм... время!

*Сравни вот с другими сочетаниями с приложениями:*

*Пароход "Леонид Брежнев"* — это судно одновременно можно назвать и пароходом, и "Брежневым". Примеры: "Пароход плывёт". "Брежнев" плывёт.

*Суп уха* — эта жижа и суп, и одновременно уха. Примеры: "Я ел суп уху". "Я ел суп". "Я ел уху". Везде объект - одно и то же понятие, но названное разными именами. Более общим и более частным.

*Слово время.* *Слово* - это общее название для всех слов. *Время* - это названия одного слова. То есть "Слово время" - опять же родовое и видовое. Употребление вместе: *"Я произнёс слово "время""* и раздельно: *"Я произнёс слово"* и *Я произнёс: "Время".* Одно и то же имеется в виду, но по-разному названное.

Твой пример: *Я расскажу о понятии "время".* Ведь так выходит: *"Я расскажу вам об этом понятии"* и одновременно *"Я расскажу вам о времени".* Одно и то же мы имеем в виду, но разные имена даём.

Можно, кстати, оформить и так: "Я расскажу о таком понятии, как время" - где приложение "время" фактически упрятано в сравнительный оборот с союзом "как". Так будет "понтовее".

Короче, ***"понятие время"*** - это сущ + сущ.-приложение. Одно и то же, но общее и конкретное. Тип синтаксической связи тут - аппозитивность. Приложение стоит в именительном падеже и неизменяемо. Некоторые, впрочем, называют неизменяемое приложение примыкающим.

В корпусе в сходных сочетаниях именительный падеж приложения берётся чаще в кавычки:

> В «Тимоне Афинском» ***понятие «пространство»*** выражено словами «море
>   воздуха». Вместо «кислое выражение лица» находим «уксусное выражение
>   лица» («Vinegar aspect», Merch., I, 1, 54);

Или так:

> Само ***понятие «время»*** в европейской культуре есть результат
>   объективизации отношения раньше-позже в сочетании с представлением о
>   веществе, субстанции.

Бывает и без кавычек:

> В полярных путешествиях ***понятие время суток*** приобретает помимо
>   абсолютного еще и относительный смысл.

---

***2. Понятие времени***

Формально-синтаксически это можно интерпретировать так:

Тут, скорее всего, есть сочетание определяемого слова (*понятие*) и зависимого слова в родительном падеже (*времени*).

В качестве типа синтаксической связи тут можно усмотреть управление, если, конечно, широко толковать это понятие, видя его там, где при любом главном слове стоит фиксированный падеж зависимого.

Например, отвлечённые существительные требуют родительного падежа, проясняющего их содержание. См.: чувство (чего?) страха, гримаса (чего?) ужаса , состояние (чего?) тревожности, задачи (чего?) войны и т. д. Никакой другой падеж тут более невозможен: нельзя сказать "чувство страхом", "чувство о страхе" и т. д. Ну чем не управление? Такой родительный падеж называется ***родительным содержания.***

Так вот, сочетание ***понятие (чего?) времени*** — и можно понимать как аналогичное вышеприведённым словосочетание с присубстантивным управлением, где зависимое слово "времени" - это родительный падеж, указывающий на содержание главного (управляющего) слова - "понятие".

Короче, главное слово — *понятие* — "диктует" форму родительного падежа зависимому слову — *время*. Понятие (чего?) времени.

Понятие (чего?) времени - тут "чего?" есть только лишь падежный вопрос, который лишь проясняет форму зависимого слова. Вопрос же смысловой (логический) - это всё же "какой?".

Понятие (какое? с чем связанное? о чём оно?) — понятие времени.

И вот в сочетании "понятие времени" - родительный падеж и можно  как раз (почему нет?) квалицифицировать как родительный содержания. Он ближе всего к  ***родительному содержания.*** Родительный содержания конкретизирует содержание отвлечённого существительного, называет то, что "внутри" у такого существительного. "Внутри" как признак предмета. См.: чувство страха, цель бытия, жанр триллера и т. д.

Таким образом словосочетание "понятие времени" абсолютно легально, это словосочетание с управлением, где управляемая форма имеет - в широком смысле - АТРИБУТИВНОЕ значения. Она называет признак главного слова, общую характеристику. ***Понятие*** (в целом какое? о чём оно? про что говорить будешь?) ***времени.***

На уровне учения о членах предложения сочетание "понятие времени" можно разобрать как определяемое слово (понятие) и несогласованное определение (времени). Хотя, кстати сказать, в некоторых учебниках и справочниках есть точка зрения, что присуществительный родительный содержания является не определением, а дополнением. У Розенталя точно есть такая мысль.

Примеров таких словосочетания  в корпусе миллион:

Вот:

> ***Понятие совести*** сгущается до материального явления, ее можно даже
>   увидеть, как предмет

Вот:

> Виктор не знал, сколько продлится ожидание. Само ***понятие времени***
>   утратило для него всякое значение

Или сюда посмотри:

> Так повелось, что с младых лет ***жанр «комедия»*** у меня
>   ассоциируется только с именем Леонида Иовича Гайдая

И вместе с тем:

> Когда театр уходил в ***жанр комедии***, возникали некоторые стилистические
>   и эстетические отклонения, как в «Третьем желании» и особенно в «Голом
>   короле»

Как видно, в принципе одинаково убедительны и ***жанр "комедия"***, и ***жанр комедии***. Заметь, в первом примере слово комедия таки в кавычках.

***Итого:*** Можно писать и ***понятие "красота"*** и ***понятие красоты***, и ***понятие "время"*** и ***понятие времени***. По-моему, чаще в сходных конструкциях употребляют всё-таки вариант с родительным падежом (жанр боевика, жанр драмы, понятие чести и т. д.)

В чём разница по смыслу? Реально, ни в чём. По смыслу ***понятие*** - это основной элемент, а ***время или красота*** - это его в широком смысле признак, свойство. Различие лишь в синтаксическом оформлении: понятие "красота" - с приложением, понятие красоты - с несогласованным определением.

Comment: Реально-нереально... Сложно, что ли, написать нормально?

Comment: Как у Вас, Артём, в рифму получилось... А что же ошибку в двух местах не поправили - одно и то же понятие, там тоже (слитно). Или пробелы важнее?

Comment: Спасибо! Да уж, и самому нравится.))) А я просто выборочно только читал, слишком много написано.

Comment: Ну, выходит, не зря писал!

Comment: Ну не ставят подряд две пары одинаковых кавычек, как ты не понимаешь!

Comment: Я знаю про "" внутри «». Но бро, я же просто пишу на форуме.

Comment: @ЛиХонг Это не форум, а сайт вопросов и ответов. Здесь "работают профессионалы".

Comment: Профессионал - это тот, кто деньги за работу получает, а я за посты тут денег не получаю, поэтому мелкие ошибки могут проскакивать из-за невычитанности.

Answer (score 0):

Если согласиться с определением словаря (Философский словарь. — СПб. 1911) — «понятие в его отвлеченности противостоит конкретности восприятия; также понятие противостоит слову, которое можно трактовать как знак понятия», — то слово-знак, или, если ближе к вопросу, имя-знак должен оставаться неизменным.

В качестве примера приведу утверждение: *понятие «мужчина» не равно понятию «мужчины»*. Иное прочтение числа — не представитель пола, а вся «не лучшая» часть человечества — может вывести на иной смысл, и ясно, что вне условия наличия именительного и кавычек у второго члена неравенства обойтись нельзя.

Также кавычки как естественный атрибут необходимы рядом с предметом понятия, ибо он имеет свойство именоваться не всегда одним словом (например, *понятие «лиственное дерево»*).

Это подтверждают многочисленные примеры из НКРЯ и добротной [статьи «Понятие»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) из Википедии.

Comment: Извините. _Философский словарь. — СПб. 1911_ — ?

Comment: Брокгауза-Ефрона. с. 205. На него ссылается статья.

Comment: Да уж, мудрёно написано... Но спасибо!)

Comment: У вас, кстати, кавычки закрываются, но нигде не открываются. :) *Это подтверждают многочисленные примеры из НКРЯ и добротной статьи «Понятие» из Википедии* — не совсем могу с этим согласиться, поскольку Википедия часто попросту придерживается канцелярского стиля и те же города не склоняет.